# MYSQL improve query performance when using OR

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a very simple MYSQL table with 2 columns and I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (col1 = '123' AND col2 = '456')
                       OR (col1 = '456' AND col2 = '123')
```

Col1 and col2 are a composite primary key: `PRIMARY KEY('col1','col2')`. Each of both is also a foreign key for primary key in another table

When I ran the EXPLAIN command for the above query i got the following:

```
id  select_type  table  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       table  index   PRIMARY,col2    col2    8   NULL    1   Using where; Using index
```

The `type` in the above result is `index` which is very similar to `All` and so very likely to be slow on a large database. Is there a way to improve the above `select` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reality statements such as `likely to be slow on a large database` should be a red flag.

If you're going to have a large dataset, profiling and testing is vital to determine firstly if it will be a problem and then if it will be enough of a problem to warrant development time and cost to address.  Usually this means micro optimisations that are unlikely to have any impact on most code bases.

Anyway, lets answer the question.

Yes, hypothetically as it's us using an index file, and if you have huge amounts of data and query this table a lot potentially it can be optimised by splitting the query into multiple execution sets rather than using expressions operators within the query, if you are only going to query twice as in your example you could achieve more performance with a `union` such as:

```
(
    SELECT * FROM test 
    WHERE
    (
        col1 = 123 AND col2 = 456
    )
)
UNION 
(
    SELECT * FROM test
    WHERE
    (
        col1 = 456 AND col2 = 123
    )
)
```

An `EXPLAIN` for this query is as follows:

```
ID      SELECT_TYPE  TABLE     TYPE POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY KEY_LEN REF ROWS    EXTRA
1       PRIMARY      test      ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   Using where; Using index
2       UNION        test      ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   2   Using where; Using index
(null)  UNION RESULT <union1,2> ALL (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
```

Take a look at this SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dc07a/1/0 for a simple test case.

The language I've used in this post such as "might", "could" etc is because I've not front loaded this example with hundreds of millions of records - I would strongly suggest you do this and evaluate and profile your query in more detail.

Unfortunately with optimisation, there isn't always a clear and simple answer of doing x to get greater performance - the query optimiser is a complex beast and sometimes trying to get every drop of performance can actually cripple your application (I'm speaking from experience here) so please, unless you have to worry about these micro optimisations - don't, if you do then evaluate, profile and test it fully before deciding on an approach.

Answer (score 1):

The cost based optimiser chooses an execution plan based on the statistics it has about the table. It knows there are not many rows in there, and so it's a waste of time doing something clever. Increase the number of rows in the table dramatically and ensure you have a high cardinality (lots of different values) and run the explain plan again and you'll see the execution change.